# Use of undeclared type 'PNChannel' when trying to create a channel in Pubnub

Tags: swift, swift2, pubnub

I'm following along the Pubnub docs to create a channel named after my logged in user. Pubnub's website says to use this code:

`PNChannel *channel = [PNChannel channelWithName:user.objectId];`

I'm coding this in Swift so I changed this to the following:

`var channel:PNChannel = PNChannel.channelWithName(currentUser.objectId)`

but I get an error `Use of undeclared type 'PNChannel'`

I have `import PubNub` in the top of my view controller. I'm new to Pubnub so any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

FINAL EDIT!! Thanks to Mike I was able to get further and figure out how to subscribe to a channel, publish a message to that channel, and then get that message back so I can eventually use it in my app:

```
@IBAction func sendButton(sender: UIButton) {

        //create Pubnub channel
        config = PNConfiguration(publishKey: "YOUR KEY HERE", subscribeKey: "YOUR KEY HERE")
        client = PubNub.clientWithConfiguration(config)

        let channelName = user.objectId! as String
        //print(channelName)
        let channelArray: [String] = [channelName]
        client.subscribeToChannels(channelArray, withPresence: false)
        client.addListener(self)
        client.publish(self.messageText.text!, toChannel: channelName, compressed: false, withCompletion: nil)
    }


 func client(client: PubNub!, didReceiveMessage message: PNMessageResult!) {
        print("Received: %", message.data.message)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had trouble with this as well. I couldnt figure out how to work with channel groups. But finally i got this to work for me by just using this line to subscribe...

```
self.client?.subscribeToChannels(channels, withPresence: false)
```

Where `channels` is an array of `String`'s. Simply create your channels, which should be of type `String`, and then append all your channels to an array, such as my `channels` array, and then use the line I show above.

Also, there are two very helpful tutorials on the PubNub website that are written in Swift that can show you all the basics.

I can show you a more in depth example of my approach if you need it let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! Is there anyway to see if the code worked? I have `client.subscribeToChannels(channelArray, withPresence: false)` and Xcode seems to land on it, but I don't see that new channel anywhere in my PubNub dashboard. 

In depth examples would be fantastic. I need all the help I can get!

Comment: Updated my question so you can see the new code thanks to your help so far

Comment: OK, playing around some more and I am starting to understand. I created a "client" on the dev dashboard and subscribed to the channel. I published a test message and I saw it appear in the dev console! I would still love to see an in depth example. I eventually want to print these messages to a label on a view controller. Also, should I set the UUID? If so, how? Thanks!

Comment: GOT IT! I finally figured it out. I was able to get the message using didReceiveMessage. I updated my question for others to see. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry I haven't ben on since yesterday but awesome glad you were able to figure it out! Inside didRecieveMessage you can check which channel you recieved a message on using `if message.data.subscribedChannel = myChannel {//do something}`

Comment: Thanks! How do I implement private chat between two users? I understand subscribing to channels, but it looks like if user1 sends a message to user 2's channel, user2 will also see messages from user3. Should I just create a new channel called "user1user2" that is unique to those two users?

Comment: I am not totally clear on your questions but I think that is correct, you need to create a channel that is unique to user1 + user2  if you dont want user 3 to receive those messages

Comment: Sorry for not being clear! The PubNub docs make it sound like you should have user2 join user1's channel, but then that would mean user1 would see messages from other users. I think the best way to go is just make a channel unique to both user1 and user2

Comment: Right, that's the proper approach

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you migrated from **3.x** recently to **4.x** client family. With **4.x** there is no more **PNChannel** class. All channels and channel groups represented by **NSString** instances.

Best regards,
Sergey